# What is multi-view modeling in computer science?

Tags: machine-learning, model, computer-science, multiview

[Situation awareness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Situation_awareness) is the perception of environmental elements and events and making decisions using our understanding from the data related to a specific situation.
I have to define situation awareness more clearly, and I have to define it as "multi-view models, each with agreement/disagreement, and uncertainty".
I don't have any idea about the quoted phrase. Can anyone help me reach a better definition of situation awareness using the quoted phrase?
I appreciate your help.